# fetch para leer un archivo .csv

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, mui

estoy haciendo un proyecto con una plantilla que usa react, mui y highchats pero por algún motivo no logro hacer fetch a un archivo .csv que tengo en la carpeta public

````
   fetch('/providedData.csv')
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       return response.text();
     })
     .then(text => {
       console.log(text);  // Add this line
       return Papa.parse(text, { header: true });
     })
     .then(result => {
       // Process the data here to calculate your metrics
       const processedData = processCsvData(result.data);
       setData(processedData);
     });
 }, []); ```

según yo está todo correcto pero nada, el console.log me devuelve puro codigo de html
````